Replacing kitchen floor on concrete slab
I’m in the middle of a total kitchen remodel that involves replacing a glued LVT (luxury vinyl tile) on a concrete subfloor.
I’ve received conflicting advice from a flooring sales rep, a floor installer, and a cabinet installer regarding the tile removal and cabinet installation process.

Should the old glued LVT tiles be removed before installing new SmartCore floating planks on the concrete subfloor?
Some have advised leaving the old tiles as is, while others suggest removal for better results.

Is it okay to install the new floating flooring wall-to-wall and place the cabinets on top of the flooring?**
One professional says it’s fine to install cabinets over the flooring, while another recommends installing the cabinets first, then flooring around them.


What I’ve Tried:
I’ve consulted with professionals, but their opinions differ. I’m hoping to hear from others with experience in similar remodels.

For the cabinets, why pay money for flooring no one will see.  It is more a money issue than putting cabinets first or last.

You mentioned three parties, none of which are canonical. What does the manufacturer say? Also, please ask just one question per post. See [ask]  and take the [tour].

Also What should base kitchen cabinets sit on top of?

@crip,  It is well worth the money to do the flooring in the entire kitchen and save the labor time.  besides, i like the idea that if something is spilled, it cannot seep quickly to under the cabinet and get between the flooring and subfloor and cause an issue that possibly requires the flooring to be removed.  It's cheep insurance, especially in a rental.

@Ish, this question is different as it asks for real world experiences not what the tech data reveals.

It really doesn't. It implies that such opinions have value by their mere mention, but what really matters is what the manufacturer wants. In essence, I pose a frame challenge.

I have done LVT on a number of surfaces and over glued down vinyl and LVP. I am also familiar with the product you are planning to use and have used it on a number of projects.  I have learned this:
If the original flooring is bonded to the subfloor well and is not bubbling or loose, it is OK to lay new LVT over it.
I have laid the flooring over the entire kitchen and then placed the cabinets a few times. (However in this instance you cannot use an underlayment pad as is possible in bedroom and living rooms.) There has been no ill reaction. The work was done in rental properties. I can witness the results over time.
The most critical issue is the connection of the tiles/ planks to each other. It is essential to be sure they are fully seated to each other. Be sure each tongue is very clean. I vacuum each row before placing the next. The tiniest bit of debris can prevent a good connection.
That's it.  It really is a great type of flooring that somehow has given people more worry than it needs.

A small—not insurmountable—issue may just be transitions if there are areas with different floors, whether or not you want a flush surface.

Transitioning was never mentioned in this conversation either by me or the OP. It is not the issue here.

OP may not have considered it, focusing simply on the "do I need to remove the tiles first?" question.

"...involves replacing a glued LVT (luxury vinyl tile)"  Glued LVT is very thin, not like the ceramic tile or stone that would create a large difference in height.  The glue down type of LVT is usually only about 3mm in thickness.

The first step for installing any product is to read the literature provided to ensure a good outcome and preserve any warranty protection. Here's what it says about your questions:

Flooring can be installed over most existing hard–surface floor coverings, provided that the existing floor surface is fully adhered, clean, flat, dry, structurally sound and free of deflection.


If cabinets are to be installed on top of the flooring (including islands), that area of material must be fully adhered to the
subfloor (including an additional 2’ beyond the cabinets and islands).

Note that this guidance is for the base SmartCore product, and not the Naturals or other variants, which may have different requirements.

The OP has done their research. Their question was asking for real world experiances.

If the glued LVT is undamaged and secure to the floor, it's OK to install your floating planks over it. Going wall to wall is, in my opinion, the way to go. It prevents having to cover the gap that's required for floating floors where the cabinets are and if a change is made later, you've got flooring already there. The only disadvantage to this is the floor goes in first so it has to be protected while all the rest of the work is being done.
